# How do I parse this array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, parsing, hash

I have the following array of hashes and I need to parse all email that are not empty:

```
[{:id=>"something", :first_name=>"First", :last_name=>"Name", :name=>"First Name", :email=>"first_name@gmail.com", :gender=>nil, :birthday=>nil, :profile_picture=>nil, :relation=>nil}, 
{...},
{}]
```

I am trying to do that this way:

```
- @contacts[0].each_with_index do |c, i|
  - unless c[:email].blank?
    %tr
      %td= c[:email]
      %td= check_box_tag "email_to[]", c[:email], true
```

But I am getting error:

```
An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in users#parse_data:

  no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

How to do it right?

Comment: I'd rather see the code written so you either `reject` or `select` the appropriate array entries in your controller, prior to passing the result to your view.

Comment: I agree with @theTinMan. Fix the contacts so they are correct, rather than adjusting for it in the view, which is messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@contacts.each_with_index do |c, i| ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not good design to do a lot of processing in your views. It's understandable to have simple conditionals and loops, but heavy processing should occur in the controller.

Use something along these lines:

```
ary = [
  {:id=>"something", :first_name=>"First", :last_name=>"Name", :name=>"First Name", :email=>"first_name@gmail.com", :gender=>nil, :birthday=>nil, :profile_picture=>nil, :relation=>nil}, 
  {:id=>"something", :first_name=>"First", :last_name=>"Name", :name=>"First Name", :email=>"", :gender=>nil, :birthday=>nil, :profile_picture=>nil, :relation=>nil}, 
  {}
]

viewable_email = ary.reject{ |e| e.empty? || e['email'].empty? }
```

At this point `viewable_email` would contain only the hashes to be displayed. Your view would only loop over them.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `each_with_index` on a hash you will get an array like below

```
{:id=>"something", :first_name=>"First", :last_name=>"Name"}.each_with_index{|e,i| p e}
[:id, "something"]
[:first_name, "First"]
[:last_name, "Name"]
```

So, you cant say `e[:id]`, thats why the error. As mentioned above `@contacts[0]` will give you the hash and not an array.